# exclude elements from serializedArray

Tags: jquery

How can I get`.serializeArray` being applied of the `form` element to exclude elements with a given class? The following failed to ignore the `input` elements with class `inactive`. Thanks

`$("form:not('.inactive>input')").serializeArray();`

```
.inactive {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a disgusting answer but an answer none the less.
Not really sure how your selector works.

```
    $("form .inactive>input").attr("disabled", "true");
    $("form").serializeArray();
    $("form .inactive>input").attr("disabled", "false");
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you

```
$('form').find(':input').not('.inactive').serializeArray();
```

Comment: Did you give each input a name? I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/7pzkygm6/